# Autolayout: Center two views with Constraint Inequalities

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I want to programmatically center two or more views within a container using only constraint inequalities. It would look something like this:

[image]

I have achieved this behavior using another view to group both labels and setting its `centerXAnchor` equal to the superview's `centerXAnchor`. I'm also aware that it's possible to achieve the same goal using two spacer views. The problem is that my application will have quite a lot of views, so I'd like to use as few subviews as possible in order to save resources

I have tried using constraint inequalities (first label's leading anchor >= view's leading anchor and second label's trailing anchor <= view's trailing anchor) to center these two views but the result I get is this.

[image]

code:

```
class TestView: UIView {

let firstLabel = UILabel()
let secondLabel = UILabel()

init() {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1
    setupSubviewsConstraints()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupSubviewsConstraints() {
    self.addSubview(firstLabel)
    self.addSubview(secondLabel)

    firstLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    firstLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
    firstLabel.text = "first"
    firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    firstLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    firstLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    firstLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

    secondLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    secondLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
    secondLabel.text = "second"
    secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    secondLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    secondLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    secondLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    secondLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate. I can't mark it as a duplicate, but read [this SO documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/792/auto-layout/3969/space-views-evenly#t=201706121941369923988) on this exact topic.

Comment: I agree with @keithbhunter. To the OP - "spacer views" are pre iOS 9. UILayoutGuides... they act *like* a UIView but without the overhead... are the right route to go.

Comment: Thanks @keithbhunter for pointing it out. I'm afraid I don't have enough reputation to close my own question.